# Backend- terei problema em renomear pasta acessada em real time via php?

Tags: back-end

Os usuários acessam páginas dentro de uma pasta. Meu site possuirá uma função para os moderadores renomearem o nome da pasta caso queiram.
O que aconteceria se a pasta estivesse sendo acessada e algum moderador alterasse o nome dela?

Observação1: O link para acessar o arquivo dentro da pasta é baseado no banco de dados, isto é, não haverá problema de "página não encontrada" ao mudar o nome da pasta, pois o novo nome irá para o BD.

1) Não conseguiria renomear, pois a pasta está tendo acesso
2) Os que já carregaram, nada acontecerá. Os que irão carregar, nada acontecerá também porque acessará já com o novo nome. Situação ideal. Não acontecerá nenhum problema com os usuários.
3) O mesmo do número dois, contudo acontecerá um problema: os que tiverem carregando no momento exato irão cair em página não encontrada.

O que me recomendam, baseado na resposta?
Se tiver algum problema ao renomear, penso em criar uma tabela com o novo nome da pasta q o moderador quer renomear junto com o nome antigo, e passar tudo no while quando o site tiver em manutenção mensal. Seria gambiarra?

Estou desenvolvendo o site para estudo, são situações hipotéticas.
Acredito que não seja possível renomear com acesso de usuários, mas não sei. Não fiz o teste na prática porque o site ainda está sendo desenvolvido quando surgiu essa curiosidade.

Comment: Uma pergunta importante, pra que renomear a pasta e modificar a estrutura?

Comment: É porque as pastas são módulos, cada módulo tem várias tarefas.
É um site de estudo. Os "moderadores" criam módulos e tarefas, assim como editam-as.
Cada modulo tem vários leveis e cada level tem várias tarefas para o usuário completar.
Talvez eu devesse fazer de outro jeito, mas o jeito que veio na mente é: 
Pastas com módulos.
Dentro delas, as pastas com leveis. Dentro das pastas com leveis (exp: pasta lvl 0) ficará as tarefas, assim:
tarefa0.php, tarefa1.php etc
Assim eu tenho mais controle
Você acha que é uma ideia ruim? Talvez eu possa modificar já que está no inicio

Comment: Pensei também em deixar as tarefas tudo misturadão numa pasta só, e definir no banco relacional de qual modulo e de qual level é aquela tarefa. Mas sla, eu gosto de deixar cada uma em cada pastinha.